# Shows different Pin images in MKMapview

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, mkmapview, mkannotation

In my MKMap view I have customized the annotation pin with an image. But still some pins are static and not showing the given image.

I am using   **-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation** to set the pin image.

Adding my code and screen here:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {


if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                 initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
    pinView.pinColor= MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

    pinView.enabled = YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bublerest.png"]; //here I am giving the image  





UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(showDetails:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rest_image2.png"]];
pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;


return pinView;
}
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you see your custom map icons at all for any pin or just some pins doesn't show them?

Answer (score 12):

If you want a different image on the `MKAnnotationView` than apples "Pin", you have to use a `MKAnnotationView` instead of a `MKPinAnnotationView`.

MKPinAnnotationView is not meant to be customized this way and will keep showing the Pin from time to time.
The [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) shows that only `pinColor` and `animatesDrop` are supposed to be changed.

You will lose the PinAnnotationView's animation and shadow, though.

Comment: While the other answers here all give ways to customise the image only this one actually states what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: I got this problem (Apple pin image instead of my pin image) in iOS9. After your suggestion now works fine ! Thanks

Comment: If you want both Apple pins (iPin?) and your own custom image show on the same map - use a custom Annotation and add a indicator as to the "type" of the annotationView required (regular or Pin). Then dequeue a annotation view or pinAnnotationView depending on the type, and handle the two cases separately.

Answer (score 2):

Create a property in the `MKAnnotation` Protocol which will be used to set the pin e.g

```
@interface AddressAnnotation1 : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mPinColor;
```

In the .m file implementation file

```
- (NSString *)pincolor{
    return mPinColor;
}

- (void) setpincolor:(NSString*) String1{
    mPinColor = String1;
}
```

When you add the `annotation`, set the `pin` color also.

```
#pragma mark annotation delegate
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(AddressAnnotation1 *) annotation
{
    UIImage *anImage = nil;

    MKAnnotationView *annView=(MKAnnotationView*)[mapView1 dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annotation"];
    if(annView==nil){
        annView=[[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotation"] autorelease];
    }
    if([annotation.mPinColor isEqualToString:@"green"])
    {
        anImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Google map pin 02.png" ofType:nil]];
    }
    else if([annotation.mPinColor isEqualToString:@"red"])
    {
        anImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Google map pin 01.png" ofType:nil]];
    }
    else if([annotation.mPinColor isEqualToString:@"blue"])
    {
        anImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Google map pin 02.png" ofType:nil]];
    }
    annView.image = anImage;
return annView;
}
```

If you don't want custom images for pins replace body of conditional statements with

```
annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
```

or

```
annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
```

or

```
annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
```

I have implemented this before. So have a go with it.

Comment: This code should work fine, but in my project it`s not working. I am also loading a KML into the map.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a sample snippet which I used in a recent project. Hope this helps.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

Annotation *annotationInst = (Annotation*)annotation;

MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"pinId";
    pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

    if ( pinView == nil ){
        pinView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                   initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID]autorelease];           
    }


    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:LOCATION_BUBBLE];

    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
}    
return pinView;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in `viewForAnnotation`

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) {
    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString* myAnnotationIdentifier = @"MyAnnotationIdentifier";

    // If an existing pin view was not available, create one
    MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:myAnnotationIdentifier];

    if ([(MyAnnotation *)annotation ann] == AnnotationTypeStart) {
        NSLog(@"In Start");
        customPinView.enabled = NO;
        customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"begin.png"];
    }
}
```

where `MyAnnotation` is implemented as below

```
typedef enum AnnotationType {
    AnnotationTypeStart,
    AnnotationTypeEnd,
    AnnotationTypeWayPoint,
} AnnotationType;

@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    AnnotationType ann;
}
```